# How to find customers who made 2nd purchase within 30 days?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need your quick help. I want to find a list of customer_id's and first purchase_date for customers who have made their second purchase within 30 days of their first purchase.

i.e. curstomer_id's 1,2,3 have made their 2nd purchase within 30 days.

I need curstomer_id's 1,2,3 and their respective first purchase_date.

I have more than 100k customer_id's.
[image]

How I can achieve this in pandas?

Comment: pls provide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

You can set a boolean mask to filter the groups of customers who have made their second purchase within 30 days, as follows:

```
# Pre-processing to sort the data and convert date to the required date format
df = df.sort_values(['Customer_id', 'purchase_date'])
df['purchase_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['purchase_date'])

# Set boolean mask
mask = (((df['purchase_date'] - df['purchase_date'].groupby(df['Customer_id']).shift()).dt.days <= 30)
            .groupby(df['Customer_id'])
            .transform('any')
       )
```

Then, we can already filter the transaction records of customers with second purchase within 30 days by the following code:

```
df[mask]
```

To further show the customer_id's and their respective first purchase_date, you can use:

```
df[mask].groupby('Customer_id', as_index=False).first()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `groupby`

```
s = df.groupby('Customer_id')['purchase_date'].apply(lambda x : (x.iloc[1]-x.iloc[0]).days<30)
out = df.loc[df.Customer_id.isin(s.index[s])].drop_duplicates('Customer_id')
```

Comment: getting error as 'IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds'

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way:

```
df2 = (df.loc[df['purchase_date']
              .lt(df['Customer_id']
                  .map((df.sort_values('purchase_date').groupby('Customer_id').first() + pd.to_timedelta(30,'d'))
                       .squeeze()))])

df2 = (df2.loc[df2.duplicated('Customer_id',keep=False)]
       .groupby('Customer_id').first())
```

or

```
df = df.sort_values('purchase_date')
m = df.assign(c1 = 1).groupby('Customer_id').rolling('30D',on = 'purchase_date')['c1'].sum().gt(1).groupby(level=0).any()
df.loc[~df.duplicated('Customer_id',keep='first') & df['Customer_id'].map(m)].sort_index()
```

or

```
p = 'purchase_date'
c = 'Customer_id'
(df.loc[df[p].le(df.groupby(c)[p].transform('min') + pd.to_timedelta('30D'))
    .groupby(df[c])
    .transform('sum')
    .gt(1)]
    .groupby(c)[p]
    .min())
```

Output:

```
Customer_id
1   2018-07-13
2   2018-06-16
3   2018-07-14
```